# argument is of length zero but is.null is false

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to check a range of numbers against some values in a dataset using for control

```
for(i in 20:28)   
{
 for(j in 1:52)
 { 
     if (Test$Ferritin[j]<15 & Test$RHCc[j]<i)
     {
         Test$Status[j] = "TP"
     }
  }     
}
```

But I keep getting the error

> Error in if (Test$Ferritin[j] < 15 & Test$RHCc[j] < i) { :    argument
>   is of length zero

I did check the condition using is.null, but it returns "False" in the answer.

Can someone explain what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is of length 0, but not all length zero vectors are `NULL` (you can confirm for yourself via `is.null(numeric(0))`). Check whether `length(argument) == 0` instead.

Comment: I did check the length of the argument; its returning a 0. But the if condition seems to be working fine if I dont use the outer for loop.

Comment: Consider posting a reproducible example if you want more help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve